# Node Js, Require is not defined in global folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, server, require

I have a node.js server to create a web chat application. But I have a problem. In one file, I want to get a function from another file with the `require` method and `module.export`. In my first file (server.js, which is in the root path), the `require` method works, but in the /js folder (which is not in the root), it does not work. I installed npm and all packages globally.

My All File :
[image: file architecture]

Code in chat.js:

```js
const {verifUserConnected, getUserInfo} = require('express');
console.log(verifUserConnected)
```

Code in connect.js :

```js
function verifUserConnected(){
    return isConnected;
}

function getUserInfo(){
    return null;
}


module.exports = {
    verifUserConnected,
    getUserInfo
};
```

In "Server.js" The `require` method works

Comment: No code no help. Complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

You've put connect.js in underneath a folder named "public" which implies you are serving it to the browser and trying to run it client-side.

Browsers do not have native support for [CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (i.e. `module.exports` and `require`).

Your starting options are:

- Rewrite the client-side code to not use modules
- Rewrite the client-side code to use [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (i.e. using `import`, `export` and `<script type="module"`).
- Transpile the modules for use on the browser (e.g. using a tool like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Parcel.js](https://parceljs.org/)

However … chat.js attempts to `require('express')`. Express will not run in the browser and doesn't export anything named `verifUserConnected` either. You'll need to address that too.

Answer (score -1):

In Common JS (Node JS works by default eith Common JS)

```
const startServer = () => {
// Code
};

module.exports = { startServer }
//Or
exports.startServer = startServer;
```

To import.

```
const { startServer } = require("./path");
```

If you have any question ask me

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.